# (Yet another) attached property binding not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I was trying to make UWP app at first, but then realized that it's too limiting for me and now trying to port existing code to classical WPF. I'm using .NET Core 3.1, Caliburn, Kinnara/ModernWpf, Microsoft.NETCore.Windows.ApiSets, Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts and System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF (though, not actually using last one).
So, basically, it should offered me quite smooth porting to WPF, but as I've found out, Caliburn's attached property View.Model was not working. I've tried to make my own attached property and bind it to VM's test property and it didn't worked either, that property never gets accessed and attached property's value is null.

Essencial code is following:

(This is not the real case, in real case I was using ContentPresenter in NavigationView.ContentTemplate, but this case should be the same in practice. And ofc I've tested with ContentPresenter outside and with NavigationView commented out. Also, if I'd use TextBlock for instance, instead of ContentPresenter, then binding works ok and attached property's value is as expected. What could be wrong and what makes ContentPresenter different?)

**ViewModel**:

```
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            ActiveItem = new SomeOtherViewModelDerivedFromScreen();
            Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(task => OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HelloWorld")));
            // This is getting called ok, though AFAIK it's not even necessary to raise PropertyChanged
        }
    ...

        public string HelloWorld => "Hello world"; // Breakpoint here, never gets called
    ...
    }
```

**Attached property**

```
    public static class Test
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", typeof(object), typeof(Test), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, 
                TestChangedCallback));

        public static object GetTest(UIElement element)
        {
            // Breakpoint here, never gets called
            return element.GetValue(TestProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTest(UIElement element, object value)
        {
            // Breakpoint here, never gets called
            element.SetValue(TestProperty, value);
        }
        private static void TestChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Breakpoint here, never gets called
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="RecipeCalculator.Views.ShellView"
        ... >
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="TestCP" t:Test.Test="{Binding Path=HelloWorld}" Content="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class ShellView : Window
    {
        public ShellView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var val = TestCP.GetValue(ViewModels.Test.TestProperty);
            // Breakpoint here, val is null.
        }
    }
```

Comment: First thing I've found out is that I should rather use ContentControl instead of ContentPresenter. I don't understand what's the difference between them...
Still, though, if I'd use ContentControl in NavigationView.ContentTemplate, attached property bindings not working. But if ContentControl is used as in this example, outside, everything's working just fine, properties is sets, View is found.

Comment: A lot of people love Caliburn Micro, but in my experience its "magic" just makes development a miserable experience when something isn't working. I would highly recommend abandoning it and using a more traditional MVVM approach.

Comment: @Keithernet I've tried "more traditional MVVM approach" just now and that was yet another miserable experiense, because WPF is pure magic. Black one. I've downloaded and referenced Caliburn sources, so at least there I can trace how things is done by someone lot more experienced at XAML than I am. But still, though, it's useless when I can't even get some simpler case to work properly.

Comment: Uh, and also doesn't look like Caliburn has something to do with it, because as I've already said, it's all attached properties not working for some reason. It would be weird to expect caliburn to work when it's attached isn't initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `ContentPresenter` with a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="TestCP" t:Test.Test="{Binding Path=HelloWorld}" 
                Content="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
```

A `ContentPresenter` is only meant to be used to display the `Content` of a `ContentControl` inside a `ControlTemplate`. It doesn't inherit a `DataContext` and that's why your binding doesn't work.

Comment: I've just found it, literally a minute ago. I'm currently posting my answer.

Comment: Why post a copy of my answer instead of accepting it? It can't be more spot on.

Comment: Because it's not a copy of your answer. And actually your answer wasn't complete for my case, because as I've said in question, main issue was with AttachedProperty in NavigationView, and even if I'd replace ContentPresenter with ContentControl that wouldn't fix it, because I had also add binding to ContentTemplate.
But if you wish so, okay, I'll accept your answer, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

After A LOT of tests and trials and googling I've figured it out.

Kinnara/ModernWpf was using ContentPresenter, which drops DataContext [as stated in this article](https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/wpf-the-real-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter/). Also, it's ContentPresenter/ContentControl wasn't binded in template to ContentTemplate, ContentTemplateSelector and ContentStringFormat, and therefore ContentTemplate I've set was never actually used, because it wasn't binded by control. After fixing source code, everything works fine.